Buy Tech Telegram Bot
Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but I have a telegram channel and my partner wants to setup a "Buy Tech" buy bot that posts to the telegram channel whenever someone buys our token. We had a different buy bot setup (Dext Buy Bot) and it was easy to setup. However, he like another one because it prints out a list of tokens on trending, and Dext I don't think has this feature.
I found a YouTube vide on how to set it up buy it says you need to search for "buy bot tech", and one with a green and white icon is supposed to pop up. However, I can't find it searching for that. I found a few different ones with that green and white logo, called different things, but it seems like they all are broken.  I guess this one was made as part of a crypto project, and I am thinking the developers might have just took it offline.
Does anyone know anything about this? If I had some doc's or something, I could probably get it up, but there is like zero info about it online, except for that one YouTube video that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks

Did you try asking on twitter, reddit or likedin? Those networks seems more suited for product recommendations. This site is more about technical questions.
